# Code won't print the string output I want, it just repeats one word

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, char

The code prints some lines from a .csv file, but there's a bug in a sequence of a code and I am not sure where.

*It prints them the following way:*

hello

how

are you

buddy

buddy buddy buddy buddy

```
const char* getfield(char* line, int num)
{
    const char* tok;
    for (tok = strtok(line, ",");
        tok && *tok;
        tok = strtok(NULL, ",\n"))
    {
        if (!--num)
            return tok;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int lang1()
{
    fp = fopen("lang.csv", "r");
    int i = 0;
    char line[1024];
    const char* word[256];
    char num[] = { 1 , 2 };
    while (fgets(line, 1024, fp))
    {
        printf("%s\n", getfield(line, num[0]));
        word[i] = getfield(line, num[0]);
        ++i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%s ", word[i]);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

*How it should actually print them:*

hello

how

are you

buddy

hello how are you buddy

*Thank you for your patience, I'd love to fix this (and have an explanation for the issue, if possible - I am trying to understand the problem)...*

Comment: The mysterious `getfield` function is probably *very* important, and should be [part of your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57449165/edit). Single stepping this in a *debugger* would probably be revealing as well.

Comment: Mathematician's list of primes: `1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,...`. Scientist's list of primes: `1,3,5.7,9 (experimental error),11,13,15 (experimental error), ...`. Computer programmer's list of primes: `1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Added the function. I tried debugging it and it says "word - 0x010ff478 Error reading characters of string, 0xcccccc Error reading characters of string; word[i] - 0xcccccc Error reading characters of string" for the first printf(...) and word[i].

Comment: @user207421 1 is not a prime number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) doesn't return different new strings, but rather pointers to the same string (the "source" argument). That is, you will always get pointers to the *single* array `line`. Which will only contain the last line you read.

This would have been very obvious if you stepped through the code in a debugger, as you would then see the pointer returned by `strtok` to always be the same.

---

Possible solutions is to use an array of arrays, and [copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) the "string" returned by `getfield`.

```
char word[256][256];
...
strcpy(word[i], getfield(...));
```

Comment: Thank you! That's really helpful to know. But I cannot think of any other function to use beside strtok for doing the job as I am not so experienced. Can you give me a tip on it, please?
EDIT: Actually I got an idea, thank you again